# ASUS M4N68T-M LE V2 bios setup

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, kali-linux

I cleared my BIOS chip in motherboard ASUS M4N68T-M LE V2 and I added the latest update with usb. After it finished writing it rebooted and said

> "enter the setup to recover BIOS your system will shut down in 15 sec"

and after this it shuts down

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Power on your computer.

Enter into BIOS setup. In very few cases after BIOS update it happens automatically. In most cases you will need to press some 'secret' key on your keyboard almost immediately after power on. Very often it is one of 'insert', 'delete', 'F2', 'F8', 'F10' keys. Watch your display. BIOS can display hint message saying something like 'hit Del key to enter setup'.

When in BIOS setup do 'load default settings' and 'save settings' (it can be menu item or some shortcut key).